# Making only top level file exempt in Django EXEMPT_URLs

Tags: django

I want to make only the /about/ page exempt -- NOT about/what_next.

How do I do this in the following code?

```
AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS = [
    r"^/about",
    r"^/about/privacy/",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `$` at the end of the URL to mark the end of the pattern

```
AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS = [
r"^/about/$",
```